Riemann-Silberstein vector with complex electric and magnetic fields?
Typically, the Riemann-Silberstein vector is defined as F=E+icB,
with both fields being real. Consequently, we get the electric field as the real part of F, and the magnetic field as the imaginary part.
The question arises whether it  makes any sense to have the RS vector if the E and B fields themselves are complex, which is often the case. Then, it seems, the RS vector would mix up the real part of E with the imaginary part of B, and vice versa. I found this kind of construction in the work of P. Hillion, Opt. Commun. 107, (1994)327 and  cannot understand it.
